# Is it possible to query a JSON file with GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, json, graphql

Is it possible in a nodejs app to save data as an JSON file and query that JSON file with GraphQL to get specific data? I dont really understand how GraphQL works, but on their page is written: "(GraphQL) [...] can be used with any kind of database or even no database at all." So how can I use a JSON file instead of a database for GraphQL?

Comment: In short, yes! You would be treating your json as file storage and reading + writing from that. To help you with on how to achieve it, we need to know what is your backend/ server side programming lang etc. and what you have done so far

Comment: The data needs to be stored for an Electron App, so the backend is node.js. Until now I played around with SQLite and NeDB for the storage of millions of data rows. I saw GraphQL and wondered if it is possible to query JSON files and how it would perform. Since I found out about GraphQL a few days ago I didnt implement anything with it yet.

Comment: If the amount of data is going to be small, typically like you know a settings configurations etc, then you can go ahead use a Json file as storage. Otherwise I wouldn't recommend it.